# Mutual Recursion Question

Tags: java, recursion, mutual-recursion

How do I change two functions that are Mutual Recursive to each other to make them into a linear recursion? Do I have to have both the methods in a single method?

Comment: Perhaps you can illustrate with a short code sample what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: how did you manage to get mutual recursion in the 1st place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to simply "inline" the implementation of the second method, into the first method.

That is,

```
public static void methA() {
    // snippet 1

    methB();

    // snippet 2
}

public static void methB() {
    // snippet 3

    methA();

    // snippet 4
}
```

becomes

```
public static void methAB() {
    // snippet 1

    // snippet 3

    methAB();

    // snippet 2

    // snippet 4
}
```

If the second method is long, and called from multiple points in the first method, it may get messy though.